# What is consistent way reporting logs from cocoa and C++ (NSLog and cout ?)

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa

I have a cocoa application core library is C++ which cocoa app uses.
I need to put logs in both parts of the app so that I can easily diagnose the issues when the logs are reported from users via crash log reporter (a separate component).

The cocoa part of the app the logs are like

```
NSLog(@"something..");
```

In the C++ library which is a separate project in C++ (not .mm but .h and .cpp) I would like to have similar logs. so if I do

```
cout<<"log from C++";
```

I don't seem to get the logs in the crash log reporter (an objective C component) if the program crashes. It only seem to be able to report logs from the objective C. I do however see the log messages from C++ on the output screen but it does not seem to do the job of writing the same to the file as well so that if the program crashes the logs are there to be reported.

So what is the best way to consistently write logs which are also reportable if the program crashes. Given the program is cocoa and uses separate C++ components.

**EDIT**

The crash reporter that I use is https://github.com/tcurdt/feedbackreporter
and one of the example log is located at the following path on my machine: /Users/myusername/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/MyApp_2013-09-08-220142_mymac.crash

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how and from where your crash log reporter is collecting the logs. `NSLog()` writes the logs to two destinations, stderr and the ASL (Apple System Log) database.

So, one step to getting the C++ logs to go to a similar location as `NSLog()` would be to use `cerr` instead of `cout`. However, the most reliable way to get them to go to the same places would be to use the ASL API from the C++ code. See the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html). Peter Hosey also explored ASL in a series of blog posts (starting [here](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-01-19/next-week-apple-system-logger)) which you may find useful.

Comment: `NSLog` is basically just a wrapper around logging to the Console facility, so you shouldn't have to drop down to ASL if all you want to do is log to the Console. Any such output appearing in crash logs is a new one on me, though—AFAIK, the closest thing is the “Application Specific Information” section, and the only way to fill that out is to set an undocumented global variable. If the questioner is using some kind of third-party crash reporter, it would depend on how that is retrieving the logs.

Comment: He wants a facility to use from a C++ library, not Cocoa, which is why I suggested ASL. He describes a crash log reporter which is a separate, Objective-C component, which I assumed was a custom crash log reporter, not Apple's.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fprintf, but it only show up from XCode

```
fprintf(stderr, "Log string: %s", aStringVariable);
```

While printf will show up if you're debugging from XCode, it won't show up in the Organizer Console. You can run the following command to print only to device's console:

```
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "log string");
```

You will also need to #include <sys/syslog.h> for syslog and LOG_WARNING to be explicitly declared

Answer (score 0):

Ref to https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas/blob/master/core/src/support/Log.h

```
    typedef void (*GCanvasSystemLog)(const char *tag, const char *log);

API_EXPORT extern GCanvasSystemLog gcanvasSystemLog;
```

and https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas/blob/master/core/src/support/Log.cpp

```
        if (gcanvasSystemLog) {
            gcanvasSystemLog(tag, buffer);
        }
```

thus can [let iOS also has the ability to get the log comes from cpp](https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-gcanvas/commit/848e0593b63a927996b0181293570bad8611fae4):

```
void nsLog(const char *tag, const char *log) {
    NSLog(@"%s: %s", tag, log);
}
...
    // to get the log comes from cpp
    gcanvasSystemLog = nsLog;
```